# how can solve out circular import error in django

Tags: django, django-models, overriding, importerror, abstract

I have created MeterModel and MeterAbstract in app MeterApp. MeterAbstract have Meter_number and MeterModel have related field of Meter.

I used MeterAbstract in BillModel.

```
from MeterApp import MeterModel
class BillDetailModel(BillAbstract, MeterAbstract):                  
      Bill_Name=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=False)
      .
      .
```

This is MeterApp models

```
class MeterDetailModel(MeterAbstract):                                                        
      tarrif                      = models.ForeignKey
      ca_number                       = models.ForeignKey
      last_bill_number                = models.ForeignKey(BillModel)
```

Now I want to update some field of MeterModel so I override save method to update and use

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    meter = MeterModel.objects.filter(meter_number=self.meter_number)
```

But giving error on

```
     from MeterApp.models import MeterModel
ImportError: cannot import name 'MeterModel' from partially initialized module 'MeterApp.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I solved this and use abstract fields to override save method?

Comment: can you post your MeterModel?

Comment: remove this `from MeterApp import MeterModel` from the file headers. 
Add it inside save() function like this 
```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    from MeterApp import MeterModel
    meter = MeterModel.objects.filter(meter_number=self.meter_number)
```
This should work

Comment: Did you try setting Model name as string like: `model_field = models.ForeignKey('Monelname')`

Answer (score 2):

You can import locally to avoid this (putting the import in the block of code you will use it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate **to** parameter of models.ForeignKey as string to prevent circular import dependencies see [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for more.

> This sort of reference, called a lazy relationship, can be useful when
> resolving circular import dependencies between two applications.

So your models should look like something similar to:

```
class MeterDetailModel(MeterAbstract):                                                        
      tarrif                      = models.ForeignKey
      ca_number                       = models.ForeignKey
      last_bill_number                = models.ForeignKey('BillModel')
```